# JavaScript -- while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm learning about how to use `while loop`, and came up with a scenario where `while loop` might be applicable.

Supposing that 20 or so pictures with similar urls are arranged in a page like below:
`http://img7.italian.uk/pastaimages/6253.jpg`
`http://img7.italian.uk/pastaimages/4218.jpg`
`http://img7.italian.uk/pastaimages/7657.jpg`
... (according to this pattern, only the last part of urls is different for each picture) ...

Among all the pictures that start with the url `http://img7.italian.uk/pastaimages/*`, if the first one is `http://img7.italian.uk/pastaimages/6253.jpg`, just refresh the current page.

And as long as the first picture is the "6253" one, the same action repeats itself.

But once the first picture is no longer the "6253" one, then stop that loop and click the current first picture with the `http://img7.italian.uk/pastaimages/*` url like "3585" or 8291 etc.

I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
while (// 1st image === 6253) {
    //refresh the current page
}
// once 1st image is no longer 6253, stop the loop and
// click the current first picture that ends with something like 3585, 8291 etc.
```

Comment: Why don't you use an if inside the loop? It seems like you want to continue the iteration only if the first image has a particular id.

Answer (score 0):

First get the src of your image (I would need to see you HTML, but it's something like this):

```
imgSrc = String(document.getElementById(idOfYourImage).src);
```

And apply it as a condition to your while loop:

```
while (imgSrc == 'http://img7.italian.uk/pastaimages/6253.jpg') {
    document.location.reload(); //refresh the current page
}
// loop stops automatically
```

Not sure what you mean with click the current picture.

Check out the docs on [reloading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) and on [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loops.

Comment: In the page, the newest pictures (once available) appear at the top left of the page (i.e. the 1st position). So the previously newest picture "6253" has now been moved to the 2nd position (or to the 3rd etc... once another newest pictures have been added to the page). How can I click the current newest picture at the 1st position, which has a number like "3534", "9043", or whatever else? All pictures have the same starting urls, only the last part being different. Thanks.

Comment: Click? Do you mean highlight or expand? Have you tried using an image caret?

Comment: Oh, the image is a hyperlink, which leads to another page when clicked. I want to left-single-click the image to move on to the next page. I suppose this is the command I should write at the end of this batch of code, but not sure how to write it.

Comment: So you want an image caret?

Comment: You can't left single click an image with javascript, you can only trigger it's event